# Jooq: Joining the same table twice across a three table join

Tags: mysql, jooq

So i have three tables

Parent_section(id)

Assessment_Question(id,parent_section_id)

Assessment_Answer(id,assessment_question_id)

I am trying to inner join parent_section and assessment_qestion, and left join assessment_question and assessment_Answer

So far joining parent_Section and assessment_question I have this, not sure how to do it for a third table?

```
    var queryResult= dsl.select()
    .from(PARENT_SECTION)
    .join(ASSESSMENT_QUESTION)
    .on(PARENT_SECTION.ID.eq(ASSESSMENT_QUESTION.PARENT_SECTION_ID))
    .where(PARENT_SECTION.GATE_ID.eq(gateId))
    .fetch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another join where you would have added another join in plain SQL:

```java
var queryResult = dsl.select()
    .from(PARENT_SECTION)
    .join(ASSESSMENT_QUESTION)
    .on(PARENT_SECTION.ID.eq(ASSESSMENT_QUESTION.PARENT_SECTION_ID))
    .leftJoin(ASSESSMENT_ANSWER)
    .on(ASSESSMENT_QUESTION.ID.eq(ASSESSMENT_ANSWER.ASSESSMENT_QUESTION_ID))
    .where(PARENT_SECTION.GATE_ID.eq(gateId))
    .fetch()
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, I asked a new question about a join between five tables with a different error if you get a chance to look